# Run Python Interpreter Continuously as Unity3D C# Process

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, process

I'm trying to integrate a Python library into Unity3D. Unfortunately, I cannot use IronPython as I have to use a `.pyd` which is a result of a compilation of a C++ library using Boost Python.

Thus, I simply wanted to keep a process running with a Python interpreter inside, and I would just synchronously call functions in the interpreter and read the output. I need the interpreter to stay alive as it will need to keep state over time.

What I am trying to do does not work unfortunately, and I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();

    var input = process.StandardInput;
    var error = process.StandardError;
    var output = process.StandardOutput;

    string line;

    // This would ideally "purge" the initial output from Python, 
    // even though for some reason it is terminating the process.
    Debug.Log("first output:");
    while ((line = output.ReadLine()) != null)
        Debug.Log(line);
    Debug.Log("first error");
    while ((line = error.ReadLine()) != null)
        Debug.Log(line);

    // Here I try to pass some commands to the Python interpreter.
    // Even if I remove the outputs from before, I only get
    // "invalid syntax errors" from Python.
    Debug.Log("Passing input");
    input.WriteLine("print('test')");

    // Try to read the 'test' output from Python.
    Debug.Log(output.ReadLine());

    // Exit the interpreter
    input.WriteLine("exit()");

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
```

I think there's multiple errors in here, from the way I'm trying to "flush" the output of the Python process from the way I'm trying to pass the input, but I'm not sure what to do differently.

EDIT: I think "flushing" the input by sending a couple of empty lines to Python fixes my input problems.

On the other hand, it seems getting output synchronously from a running Process is impossible, as there is no non-blocking way to check if there is more output to read. Even Peek seems to hang. I'm still looking into it..

Comment: Did you try `input.WriteLine(@"print('test')");` ?

Comment: What sort of response time do you need? How often are you calling it? Could you run your Python process as a server and communicate that way, e.g. HTTP?

Comment: @KashifSiddiqui Still get a syntax error unfortunately: `File "<stdin>", line 1 print('test') [...] SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @ColinYoung For what I am doing running it as a server could probably also work. The time Python spends doing stuff is low so I am OK with doing synchronous calls, which is what I am trying here. Do you have some suggestions in how to setup the server approach?

Comment: The simplest approach would be to set up an HTTP server (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) and communicate with that using UnityWebRequest. If you're trying to do per-frame calculations that will likely be too slow, but given that you are attempting to parse stdout I'm guessing that's not the case. Do you _have_ to use Python? Unity supports [native plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) which would allow you to call the C++ library directly.

Comment: @ColinYoung I only need a couple of calls done upon user interaction, nothing really expensive. I know about the native plugin, but I would have to create a C api, while I already had the Python one. I'll look up the server approach thanks. At the moment I'm trying to work with the brittle approach of being sure to read output only when I know it's there, so that everything does not hang. I'll try to improve on it later, but as it's for a simple demo quality of code is not that important thankfully.

Comment: Given that update, I'd definitely go with a local HTTP server approach. In my experience, simple "demo code" tends to live well beyond its best-before date :)